# Importing specific material icon

Tags: html, css, material-design, material-ui, google-material-icons

I am creating a web application which uses [Google's Material Icons](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/).
Nearly all of the icons I use are of the default 'filled' style, and 1 one is of the 'outlined' style.
I import the icons with the following CSS code:

`@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|');`

This imports two .woff font files, one for the default 'Material Icons' font-family, and one for the 'Material Icons Outlined' family.

Given that I am only using 1 icon from the outlined family, is there a way to only import that specific icon, instead of importing the entire collection (without saving locally)?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To just import the 'filled' font remove `|Material+Icons+Outlined|` from the url.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');
```

There's no official CDN that allows you to just grab one image from the web, so you'd need to download the png or svg from [icon library](https://material.io/resources/icons/?icon=accessibility&style=outline) and host it yourself.

Note that the each font file is only around 60KB-80KB (click links below to see for yourself), so if you're doing this to improve load time it's likely not going to make a huge difference.

[filled woff2](https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v50/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNcIhQ8tQ.woff2) [outline woff2](https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialiconsoutlined/v18/gok-H7zzDkdnRel8-DQ6KAXJ69wP1tGnf4ZGhUcel5euIg.woff2).

Comment: I actually don't understand what your're suggesting as a solution here

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to multi-task. See if the update helps.

Comment: So the answer is that a single icon cannot be downloaded, unless somebody proposes otherwise

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue, but decided to host the icon myself.

Didn't want to add a custom font-face, so downloaded the icon, edited the `fill="black"` parameter inside the SVG to match the color I was after and simply used it in an img tag `<img src="assets/delete-icon.svg">`.